# How to setup starting file location for a user using FTP

Tags: linux, terminal, ftp

I have a user account `rootftp` which two people use every once in awhile to ftp into a machine, I believe it is using Solaris and running as a Xerox freeflow print server. The physical machine is a Xerox N-Series, Reg Model D01D, Reg Type D01D001. The two users are running windows 10 if that affects anything. Say we have the two following paths:

```
Path 1 = /var/somewhere/somewheredeeper
Path 2 = /var/somewhere
```

When either of the two users use ftp to get to this machine, they start out in the location of path 1. Where/How can I make a change so they start out in Path 2 when they connect through ftp? They need access to Path 2 but if they start out in Path 1 they cannot go up a level higher into Path 1.

I know next to nothing about linux, but I am very slightly familiar with bash and using a terminal. I wasn't able to find this particular information from searching. Thanks for any assistance!

Comment: From your description, it seems possible that it is the server enforcing the path restriction. I would suggest communicating with the server's admin to find out if this is the case. (It's possible that it's the clients, too, but then it would be strange if they don't allow going one level up after connecting.)

Comment: @dhag, That was my thought (server is restricting acccess). There is no real administrator/manager for this machine, although I have full access to it. It is a Xerox print server that we sometimes have to move files to or from and use FTP to complete that task.

Comment: Ah, that's very useful information; if you edited your question to mention the exact model of Xerox machine that you are using, there is a chance that someone could find out more about how can be configured.

Comment: [using this link, can you determine which type of user was setup](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18752_01/html/816-4555/wuftp-10.html) - _Real_ or _Guest_ ?

Comment: the output of `getent passwd rootftp | cut -d: -f6` may also reveal `/var/somewhere/somewheredeeper`, can you verify that please?

Comment: @WEBjuju, that command does point towards the `/var/somewhere/somewheredeeper`. Is there a way I can change it to point to `/var/somewhere` ? I was unable to determine whether "rootftp" was a guest or real user

Comment: @WEBjuju, although after reading through that link you provided, I believe it might be a guest account. The access they have allows them to add/remove files through the explorer window on their windows computer, they do not have the ability to launch a terminal window like a real user could. So i'm going to give it my best guess that it is a guest user

Comment: `getent passwd rootftp | cut -d: -f6` is simply to reveal ( a ) if the user is a regular user in the solaris /etc/passwd file and ( b ) what their home dir is.  i can add it as a solution, but updating their home dir in /etc/passwd may be step 1 followed by step 2 which is updating the file/folder permissions of their new home.

Comment: you know you could just more simply `grep rootftp /etc/passwd` to see the entire line which would include the home directory...i was trying to be more precise, but however you determine the a/b of my previous comment is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very likely you just need to

1. update the user's home directory, you could `vi /etc/passwd` and change `/var/somewhere/somewheredeeper` to `/var/somewhere` but you'll then need to
2. update the permissions on `/var/somewhere` to have ownership and permissions that allow the `rootftp` user to `ftp` to that dir

Comment: Thank you very much @WEBjuju ! I was able to do that `grep rootftp /etc/passwd` and then I did `gedit /etc/passwd` and was able to edit that file and set the directory to what I want it to be for the rootftp user. Upon testing the ftp now functions perfectly

Comment: @cet51 best news of the day, sir.  congratulations - don't stop *nixing!

Comment: I'm assuming `vi` is just a different file editor? I have no clue what you mean by *nixing unfortunately

Comment: `vi` is a file editor as is `VIM` which is "Vi IMproved".  i'm probably imagining that `*nixing` is a thing by playing off the _gerund_ form of the noun *nix which seems to frequently stand for both Linux/Unix.  probably...  i am typically off _at least an inch_ on my knowledge and usage of things like that.  anyway, i just said it because you had mentioned that you were new to linux, so i though i would encourage you to continue your foray into *nix in the wake of your success with editing the users' home directories.  best of luck with the solaris box.